# Why is it said that in practical cases loop gain of an oscillator should be slightly greater than unity?

Tags: oscillator

Recently I read about oscillators and I noted a sentence. It is said that in practical cases the loop gain should be somewhat 5% larger than unity. Why is it said so?Will it result in increasing the amplitude to an unexpected limit?

Comment: Less than unity would produce a dampened wave. Over unity allows oscillations to build up. Stability is increased when amplitude is stabilized in the linear range of the amplifier.

Comment: I suppose the amplitude will go on increasing, can you please explain

Comment: Any amount over unity will eventually allow the amplitude to increase until operating voltage is reached or distortion is reached from circuit clipping. Digital oscillators just switch on/off creating a square wave output. Many circuits have been built thought the years to stabilize the output voltage (AGC, Automatic Gain Control) for sine wave output. Many years ago a bridge circuit was created to improve feedback stability, (Wien oscillator for low frequencies)(Meacham oscillator, for crystals).

Comment: extra reading http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/1999/HPL-1999-6.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an oscillator to be stable, it is necessary that the net loop gain over the course of a cycle be *exactly* one.  If one is using a circuit where increases in instantaneous amplitude, at least beyond a certain point, will cause a reduction in gain, then the circuit will oscillate at a level where the gain is sometimes above one and sometimes below one, with the "greater" and "less" parts balancing out over the course of a cycle to yield a net gain of exactly one.  Since most amplifier circuits have a gain which naturally falls off as instantaneous amplitude increases beyond a certain point, setting the low-amplitude gain to be slightly greater than one will usually achieve the conditions necessary for oscillation.

Note that if there is much difference between the minimum and maximum gain during a cycle, that difference will cause distortion in the output wave.  If the purpose of the circuit is to produce a "wibble wave", and one doesn't care whether the wave is a particularly clean sinusoid, one may use a circuit whose low-amplitude gain is quite high, and whose gain falls off rapidly as the signal approaches the desired amplitude; this will yield a reasonably-quickly-starting oscillator which with predictable output amplitude, but the wave will be pretty distorted.  Having gain fall off more gradually with amplitude, and having the zero-amplitude gain be just above unity, may reduce distortion, but such an oscillator will slower to start, and have a less predictable output amplitude.  Controlling gain based upon a multi-cycle average amplitude may allow the circuit to start quickly while yielding very low distortion, but adds complexity.

One rather clever approach for controlling gain based upon multi-cycle amplitude is to use a light bulb in the feedback circuit.  The resistance of a lightbulb will increase with temperature, which will be a function of the average power dissipated by it, which will be roughly proportional to the square of the average current (not exactly proportional because of the resistance change).  If the thermal time constant of the filament is long relative to the oscillation period, the gain won't change much during the course of a cycle, thus allowing the circuit to generate a relatively clean sine wave.

Comment: "most amplifier circuits have a gain which falls off as instantaneous amplitude increases beyond a certain point" How is that possible?

Comment: @DDR: If nothing else, because amplifiers generally have a finite limit as to how much voltage they can output.  A rail-to-rail amplifier powered from +/- 10 volts is not going to amplify a 9 volt signal by more than 11.1% no matter how high its gain is configured.  It may be that its output is 150% of the input voltage until the input reaches 8V (output reaches 10V), and sits at 10V unless or until the input falls below 8V or exceeds 20V (in the latter case, bursting into flames).  That would be a rather crude way of having a device reduce gain, but it would reduce gain,.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is for sine wave oscillators. Sine wave oscillators need a loop-gain of greater than unity or they will not begin oscillating.

The time it takes to start (from scratch) oscillating also needs to be practical and sensible - you want it to be running when you apply power after all! This means that a big loop-gain gets it running quicker and, if you don't mind the sine wave hitting the power rails and clipping, life is very easy. Clipping can be regarded as a non-linear gain in that above a certain level the gain tails off to zero.

The best practice is to have a high initial loop-gain then, when the amplitude has attained a certain level (a couple of volts peak to peak but not clipping) start backing the loop-gain down to the point where it is self-sustaining.

It's really very hard to do this by design without implementing a circuit that has an amplitude monitor driving a voltage dependent resistor. The VDR controls the amplitude of the sine wave and if it drops a bit, the VDR (under control from the amplitude monitor) increases the loop-gain a bit to counteract this amplitude change: -

[image]

This is a circuit of a Wein bridge sine wave oscillator - it uses the JFET to control the loop-gain of the op-amp. The two diodes connected to the output, in conjunction with the 22uF capacitor set a negative voltage on the JFET's gate - the higher the output from the op-amp, the more negative is the JFET's control voltage and this lowers loop-gain by turning the JFET off.

JFETs are used as voltage dependent resistors like this a lot. Siliconix produced [this](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CDwQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fusers.ece.gatech.edu%2F~lanterma%2Fsdiy%2Fdatasheets%2Ftransistors%2Fvishay_fet_cvr_an.pdf&ei=J8aMUuS1LYm7hAeC8YHQDg&usg=AFQjCNGIYyj8MuejoigCR9OwW86NhnvH1A&bvm=bv.56643336,d.ZG4) document that explains how they work. It should also be noted that LEDs and LDR's can be used and that a two terminal VDR can be achieved with a filament bulb.